# "a few fallings out" or "a few falling outs"?

Tags: single-word-requests

What's the right way of saying, "a few fallings out"  or "a few falling outs"?

Comment: Historically, in the prescriptivist sense, *fallings out*; currently, in the descriptivist sense, either, but more likely "falling outs".

Comment: Both are possible and found, but I don't think the compound noun "falling-out" really lends itself to pluralisation. I'd hyphenate it though.

Comment: @BillJ - Google gives a lot of results for "a few" with "falling(s) out(s)"

Comment: @brilliant Read my comment. I said both are possible and **found**.

Comment: @BillJ - So it DOES lend itself to pluralisation then.

Comment: @brilliant For some people, apparently so.

Comment: Google Ngram returned nothing for either

Comment: @BillJ - But it does have some results for the singular "a falling out": https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+falling+out&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Ca%20falling%20out%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Ba%20falling%20out%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BA%20falling%20out%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dictionary.com gives the plural as [***fallings-out***](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/falling-out?s=t), and [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/falling-out) provides the following example sentence:

> - ‘There have been ***fallings-out*** between them before, visceral
>     back-biting and stand-up rows that are often settled long before they
>     enter the public domain.’ ***[emphasis added]***

On the other hand, [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/falling-out) indicates that the plural may be either ***fallings-out*** or ***falling-outs***, so evidently either is correct.

Comment: "Falling out" a verb-centred compound noun where "falling" is the verb and "out" is a preposition. It's the same structure as "dressing-down", "going-over", "talking-to" and so on

Comment: @BillJ Based on that, what's your take on the plural?